# VuePress: Remove external links icons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuepress

In Vuepress default theme, every time you add an external link, an icon is added to the link.

I am creating a new theme that inherits the default theme, but I would like to remove this behavior.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Which exact version of Vuepress are you using?

Comment: I believe I am using this version: "vuepress": "^1.9.7"

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no way to do this in the configs for vuepress 1. However here's what I did that's acceptable.

Use the `markdown` section of your `config.js` object to understand/control what attributes are on external links:

```
    markdown: {
        externalLinks: { target: '_blank', rel: 'noopener noreferrer' },
    },
```

Then target those links. I'm using the [`has` selector](https://caniuse.com/css-has) to make sure the entire span that wraps the svg is removed, so there aren't any spacing quirks. `has` isn't perfectly supported, but it's good enough.

```
a[rel="noopener noreferrer"] span:has(svg.icon.outbound)
    display: none
```